# Transaction support in psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I'm little confused reading the **psycopg2** documentation about how it handles transactions (apart from using it with `with` statement).

Reading through the [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html), I see

> By default, Psycopg opens a transaction before executing the first
>   command: if commit() is not called, the effect of any data
>   manipulation will be lost.

Assuming the above statement to be correct

```
dbconn = psycopg2.connect(...)   cursor = dbconn.cursor()
cursor.execute("insert record into a") 
cursor.execute("insert record into b")

cursor.execute("insert record into c") // This throw integrity error.
cursor.execute("commit") // this logs "WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress"
```

The data manipulation for `a`, `b` would get **lost**.

But as I see it, this is not happening on PostgreSQL. I'm definitely missing something over here, but right now I am not sure what and where.

Comment: What don't you see on postgresql? What's not happening? Following your code I find it hard to establish if the error is something you expected or didn't and the same for commit.

Comment: @KamilGosciminski sorry I do not remember. I accidentally bountied this question as against to the other question.

Comment: @KamilGosciminski but you can still answer the question .. what I'm trying to address is given the `psycopg2` open a transaction in the first statement the `commit` statement would not have resulted in warning i.e  `"WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be in autocommit mode.

The warning is what you get when you issue `COMMIT` when no explicit transaction has been started (PostgreSQL is in autocommit mode by default!).

Use a statement like

```python
print(dbconn.autocommit)
```

to verify that autocommit is enabled.

To change the property, simply use

```python
dbconn.autocommit = False
```